# How to generate App Registration data in SharePoint Online through PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, provider-hosted-app

Is it possible to register app through PowerShell on **SharePoint Online(Office 365)**? i.e the conventional way where registering app data(Client Id, Client Secret..) is done on `AppRegNew.aspx` page.

I am aware that it can be done on **On-Premises** by using `Register-SPAppPrincipal` but it seems that `Register-SPAppPrincipal` is not supported on **SharePoint Online**.

How can we register app data on SharePoint Online via PowerShell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need the `MSOnline` module, which you can download from [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28552.microsoft-azure-active-directory-powershell-module-version-release-history.aspx#Release_overview) (I have 1.1.166.0, I cannot say if this will work on an older version).

The following worked for me:

```
$clientId = [System.Guid]::NewGuid()
$appDomain = "HelloWorld.windowsazure.net"
$appName = "Hello World Test App"
$servicePrincipalName = @("$clientId/$appDomain")
$appUrl = "https://HelloWorld.windowsazure.net/Home/Index"

Connect-MsolService

New-MsolServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalNames $servicePrincipalName -AppPrincipalId $clientId -DisplayName $appName -Addresses (New-MsolServicePrincipalAddresses -Address $appUrl)

$bytes = New-Object Byte[] 32
$rand = [System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator]::Create()
$rand.GetBytes($bytes)
$rand.Dispose()
$clientSecret = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)

New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $clientId -Type Symmetric -Usage Sign -Value $clientSecret
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $clientId -Type Symmetric -Usage Verify -Value $clientSecret
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $clientId -Type Password -Usage Verify -Value $clientSecret

Write-Host "Client ID`t: $clientId`r`nClient Secret`t: $clientSecret"
```

I managed to scrounge this up from these sources:

- [Replace an expiring client secret](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn726681.aspx#Generate%20a%20new%20secret)
- [Manage service principals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn919672.aspx)
- [New-MsolServicePrincipal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn194110(v=azure.98).aspx)
- [New-MsolServicePrincipalAddresses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn169221(v=azure.98).aspx)